# how do you mock dependent methods using rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, rspec2

I'm trying to write a custom parser for my cucumber results.  In doing so, I want to write rspec tests around it.  What I currently have is as follows:

```
describe 'determine_test_results' do
  it 'returns a scenario name as the key of the scenario results, with the scenario_line attached' do
    pcr = ParseCucumberJsonReport.new
    expected_results = {"I can login successfully"=>{"status"=>"passed", "scenario_line"=>4}}
    cucumber_results = JSON.parse(IO.read('example_json_reports/json_passing.json'))
    pcr.determine_test_results(cucumber_results[0]).should == expected_results
  end
end
```

The problem is, `determine_test_results` has a sub method called `determine_step_results`, which means this is really an integration test between the 2 methods and not a unit test for `determine_test_results`.

How would I mock out the "response" from determine_step_results?

Assume determine_step_results returns {"status"=>"passed", "scenario_line"=>4}

what I have tried:

```
pcr.stub(:determine_step_results).and_return({"status"=>"passed", "scenario_line"=>6})
```

and

```
allow(pcr).to receive(:determine_step_results).and_return({"status"=>"passed", "scenario_line"=>6})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize stubs for what you're trying to accomplish. [Project: RSpec Mocks 2.3](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-3/docs/method-stubs) would be good reading regarding this particular case. I have added some code below as a suggestion.

```
describe 'determine_test_results' do
 it 'returns a scenario name as the key of the scenario results, with the scenario_line       attached' do
   pcr = ParseCucumberJsonReport.new
   expected_results = {"I can login successfully"=>{"status"=>"passed", "scenario_line"=>4}}

   # calls on pcr will return expected results every time determine_step_results is called in any method on your pcr object.
   pcr.stub!(:determine_step_results).and_return(expected_results)

   cucumber_results = JSON.parse(IO.read('example_json_reports/json_passing.json'))
   pcr.determine_test_results(cucumber_results[0]).should == expected_results
 end
end
```

Comment: Better use the new `expect` API - `allow(pcr).to receive(:determine_step_results).and_return(expected_results)` https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#method-stubs

Comment: Neither one of these worked, I changed the scenario_line number to 6 and expected a "exepected {"I can login successfully"=>{"status"=>"passed", "scenario_line"=>4}} got {"I can login successfully"=>{"status"=>"passed", "scenario_line"=>6}}

Comment: @UriAgassi see my previous comment

Comment: @MattWestlake didn't you mean to write `allow(pcr).to receive(:determine_step_results).and_return({"status"=>"passed", "scenario_line"=>4})`?

Comment: @UriAgassi I wrote "scenario_line"=>6 to make sure the mock was overriding the actual function.  If it did, I would have expected the failure to show "expected "scenario_line"=>4 got "scenario_line"=>6" but it didn't.

Comment: Nevermind, I was overwriting the variable in my other method.  Either way works, using the "allow(pcr)" way as that seems to be the more up to date way of mocking.

Answer (score 0):

If all what `determine_test_results` does is call `determine_step_results`, you should not really test it, since it is trivial...

If you do decide to test it, all you need to test is that it calls the delegate function, and returns *whatever* is passed to it:

```
describe ParseCucumberJsonReport do
  describe '#determine_test_results' do
    it 'calls determine_step_results' do
      result = double(:result)
      input = double(:input)
      expect(subject).to receive(:determine_step_results).with(input).and_return(result)

      subject.determine_test_results(input).should == result
    end
  end
end
```

If it is doing anything more (like adding the result to a larger hash) you can describe it too:

```
describe ParseCucumberJsonReport do
  describe '#determine_test_results' do
    it 'calls determine_step_results' do
      result = double(:result)
      input = double(:input)
      expect(subject).to receive(:determine_step_results).with(input).and_return(result)
      expect(subject.larger_hash).to receive(:merge).with(result)

      subject.determine_test_results(input).should == result
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: determine_step_results is not the only thing that's happening, it is also placing the results into a larger hash.  Also it is hard to understand what is going on in your example as "subject" is not defined and neither is input or result.